# Defining 'UITableViewCell' variable in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create UITableViewCell type variable with swift, these are my codes:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dwarves.count
    }
```

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(simpleTableIdentifier)! as UITableViewCell
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier)
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = dwarves[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}`

In 7th line **if (cell == nil)**, it gives me an error that **Value of type 'UITableViewCell' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed**.
It can't be replaced by **if ( !cell )**. How should I fix the codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use the outdated method `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:)` you can do it like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(simpleTableIdentifier) ?? UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier)
    cell.textLabel?.text = dwarves[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

But you should preferably use [`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:forIndexPath:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:) which never returns `nil`.
It is used along with [`registerClass(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:) and [`registerNib(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:).

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:), `dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns an optional value :

```
 func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell?
```

But in your code, you explicitly unwrap this value because your cell object is an `UITableViewCell` object.

You should use `- dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` : its return value is not optional thus you don't have to unwrap your cell.

Answer (score 0):

Because the non optional type cannot be compared with `nil` (Only optional variables contains `nil` value). Like if you want to check `nil` then just use that way. i implemented it in `Playground`

```
let tableView = UITableView()
let index = NSIndexPath()
var cell:UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("")
//then make check for nil if you want
if (cell == nil) {
    print("its nil")
} else  {
    print("not nil")
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I have censor 'cell' and it received the nil. But just how to censor all the probable value if would be the nil among them.